# The click on actor not fireing UE4

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreachable-code

I have a problem i think it's very easy to solve but i have tried to solve but i failed.

[image: Image From Game]
The problem is
i have 2500 actor in world (2d sprites)
i am trying to make actor listen to clicking events with 4 ways but all have failed

**1st way**

```cpp
    OnClicked.AddUniqueDynamic(this, &AWorldUnitSprite::OnSelected);
```

**2nd way**

```cpp
void AWorldUnitSprite::NotifyActorOnClicked(FKey ButtonPressed)
{
    Super::NotifyActorOnClicked(ButtonPressed);
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Am here 15"));

}
```

**3rd way**

```cpp
void AElkaisarController::SetupInputComponent()
{
    Super::SetupInputComponent();
    check(InputComponent);
    InputComponent->BindAction("MouseClick", IE_Pressed, this, &AElkaisarController::OnMouseClick);
}

void AElkaisarController::OnMouseClick()
{
    FHitResult HitResult;
    GetHitResultUnderCursor(ECollisionChannel::ECC_Pawn, false, HitResult);

    if (HitResult.GetComponent())
    {
        GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 2, FColor::Red,    FString::Printf(TEXT("Mouse Click+++ Component: %s"), *HitResult.GetComponent()->GetName()));
    }

    if (HitResult.GetActor())
    {
        GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 2, FColor::Red, FString::Printf(TEXT("Mouse Click+++ Actor: %s"), *HitResult.GetActor()->GetName()));
   }

}
```

All three ways failed to trigger click events
My controller class is enabling click events
Code:

```cpp
AElkaisarController::AElkaisarController()
{
    bEnableClickEvents = true;
    bEnableTouchEvents = true;
    bShowMouseCursor = true;
    bEnableMouseOverEvents = true;
    bEnableTouchOverEvents = true;


}
```

and My Actor constructor is
Code:

```cpp
AWorldUnitSprite::AWorldUnitSprite(const FObjectInitializer& ObjectInitializer)
: Super(ObjectInitializer)
{
    // Set this pawn to call Tick() every frame. You can turn this off to improve performance if you don't need it.
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;

//Create a default UPaperSpriteComponent and register it to this Actor
    Sprite = ObjectInitializer.CreateDefaultSubobject<UPaperSpriteComponent>(this, TEXT("SpriteComp"));
    RootComponent = Sprite;
    ObjectInitializer.CreateDefaultSubobject<APawn>(this, TEXT("MovementComp"));
    bBlockInput = false;
    EnableInput(UGameplayStatics::GetPlayerController(GetWorld(), 0));

}
```

I have searched for the solution but found no thing helps me
thanks for your help

Comment: Can't help, while facing the same problem.

Comment: i found the problem in z-index in 2d it was too large when i reduce its value it works with no problem

Comment: Lucky！I am dealing with a spawn actor with component, can't figure it out.

Comment: when you spawn actor check y value (depth of actor in world) it should be small value

Comment: Thanks, while as i'm new, just didn't add UFunction to  AddUniqueDynamic function.